# Armory takes 8 Hours to sync. Is it going to get worse as Bitcoin becomes more popular?

Tags: synchronization, scalability

I have been experimenting with Bitcoin and I installed Armory wallet. It told me that it would take approximately 8 hours to sync the worldwide ledger.

My question is, as Bitcoin gets more popular, will it take longer to download the ledger?

If so, doesn't this pose a problem - could it get to big to be feasible?

Comment: Please see further detail on my question.  It is distinctively different, as I would like to know if the growth will cause a problem.  Thanks :)

Comment: Regarding that edit: Possible duplicate of [Are there any studies into the size of the blockchain scaling over time?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2798/5406), [How big will the block chain become?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/8712/5406), [Can blockchain size become a blocker for bitcoin adoption?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/20368/5406) ;)

Comment: It's a good question, but it has been asked a few times already. :)

Comment: Although this question is in principle a duplicate, it's so that Armory does not really downloads the blockchain, but parses it from Bitcoin-Qt. But they are working on changing that so that it does not take 8 hours every time you open the client. Not sure how far they are with that.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be yes, if the chain 
becomes bigger it takes more time to download
it.

The more detailed answer would be: there is 
plenty of options to make it quicker: for
example you can download already constructed
chain from some trusted source.

Comment: No, blockchain grows with time, not with popularity bigger blocks can be a factor but are not the main issue.

Comment: The question was if it is going to take more time, the answer is yes it will because it become larger.

Comment: Both in title and description the question is linked with Bitcoin becoming more popular and even if Bitcoin become less popular and even abandoned except for a minority the blockchain will continue growing. So no blockchain size problem has nothing to do with popularity.

Comment: what about much more transactions data in each block ? 
common take the -1 off :)